# Email enabled list item added

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I am currently developing an event receiver for an email enabled list and I'm confused as to how to correctly handle the item being added to the list.

On one hand I have the ItemAdded event and on the other I have the EmailReceived event. Now I understadn these are two different events but why wouldn't or couldn't I use the ItemAdded event opposed to the EmailReceived event? Does the EmailReceived call the ItemAdded event from within or is there something that I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Item added event for that.You can use Email Received method to trap the event when list receive an email message

***Email Received is fired just after the incoming email is received to the list before any other item event receivers***

Item adding is also fired after that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to understand. The way I understand thing s is that the EmailRecieved handles adding the item to a list, and that there is no need to handle ItemAdding anymore

Comment: Yes if you want to handle email messages no need to use item adding.Please upvote this if it helped you.Thanks